# PHP Initiator in IE

Tags: javascript, php, internet-explorer

I have a web page which will load an external javascript processed by PHP. In Chrome and Firefox if I want to get the initiator of the js file through PHP, I just need to get it by the superglobal variable `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]`. However, this would not work in IE if I visited another web page before browsing this web page. How can I get the initiator web page even in IE?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. How are you getting it in JavaScript? Can you show your code? PHP doesn't have anything to do with what browser your use.

Comment: Using chrome developer tool, I found that every time when I loaded the js file in a web page, it always returns with Referer header the url of that web page. This, however, will not always happen unless you reload the page.

Comment: `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]` is **not** reliable. It can be disabled or spoofed by the end user, or by a proxy. Do **not** rely on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is not processing JavaScript. Your Browser is processing JavaScript.

The HTTP headers are known to be unreliable, everyone can change their fields to whatever you want in the request. You cannot fix your problem by using `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]` nor anything in JavaScript related. Some browsers have turned off the refererrer or offer the possibility to turn it off, as some add-ons will also remove the referrer.

The only reliable way is to generate security tokens, which you will use only once per JavaScript call. Save it in a session, compare them when calling the html/php and when calling the js/php.